# What is the fastest way to change type_mapping from long to string, when having HUGE amount of data?

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, reindex

I tried once with alias index by moving data to new index, and I found it took too long, by following this guide https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime.

In addition, I have around 75 millions documents,and also growing up in every second.

I tried to move data from old index to new index with elasticdump but It's very slow.

Is there any fastest way I can change type mapping?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to create another `string` field in your mapping and modify the existing `long` one with a `copy_to` to that new field.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type -d '{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "long_field": {
        "type": "long",
        "copy_to": "str_field"      <---- copy_to new field
      },
      "str_field": {                <---- new field
        "type": "string",
        "store": true               <---- store it if you want to see it using fields=...
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

All newly indexed documents will get the new field `str_field` populated. You can also modify your indexing process to populate that new field directly in the source document you send to ES, of course. Note that if you don't, the `str_field` will only be indexed (so it can be searched) but it will not appear in the `_source`. You can still store `str_field` by adding `"store": true` for that field and then you'll be able to see its value when querying using `&fields=str_field`

For all existing documents, that field can be populated in different ways **without** having to re-index everything (that would defeat the purpose and you would simply create a new index instead), but with a cleverly set-up bulk re-indexing process just for that new field, that can be done.

Another hardcore solution would be to use the [update-by-query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery).

You still need to add the new `str_field` to your mapping, without modifying the existing one:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type -d '{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "str_field": {                <---- new field
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And then using the plugin you can issue a query such as this one that will populate the new field (and optionally remove the `long_field` from the source if you don't need it anymore:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/your_index/_update_by_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.str_field = String.valueOf(ctx._source.long_field); ctx._source.remove(\"long_field\"); "
}'
```

For that second solution, you need to make sure to enable scripting in `elasticsearch.yml` and restart ES:

```
script.inline: on 
script.indexed: on
```

Note, however, that with this second solution your new field will not be populated unless you also adapt your indexing process in order to include that new `str_field` field in the JSON documents you send to ES.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the mapping by re-creating the index, there is no way to change the mapping in-place.

So you likely need to find the fastest way to export/import the data into a new index. Instead of exporting the data out of Elasticsearch and then writing it back in you can try using one of the reindexing-plugins which may be able to keep the data locally on the nodes without the cost for the data-transfer, see e.g. https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-reindexing which looks promising.